# When were methods introduced to the Document API

Tags: javascript

For the [Javascript Document API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document), where can I find details about *when* each method was introduced to the API (don't know if I should append the term "standard" to that)?

I am currently consulting the [WHATWG Standards Document](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-document-object); however, there isn't versioning history there from what I can tell (neither is there in the [interface definition](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-document)).

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: @Barmar I am trying to investigate what a particular approach to attaching DOM listeners would have looked like in older versions of vanilla JavaScript. It is more of a curiosity question than a necessity. Figured I'd see how the community responded to the question. I can delete and/or close if it doesn't fit the standards.

Comment: You aren't understanding that JavaScript is implemented differently by each browser manufacturer. The only thing you can inspect is the ECMA Standard which does not guarantee implementation by anyone. Welcome to JavaScript!

Comment: google let's you refine dates, so you can look for articles on "new CSS3 features in Chrome 5" and whatnot, which might provide a more realistic real-world historical API usage, instead of specs which tended to lag behind browsers.

Comment: @dandavis that's a good methodology, actually. Thank you. I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: also, libs will reflect older APIs in past versions; it's fun to look at some of the hoops jquery used to jump through to work in IE7...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with most things, it is in the specifications (they are also referenced in the MDN article in your question):

- [DOM Level 1 Specification (October 1, 1998): ECMA Script Language Binding](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/ecma-script-language-binding.html)
- [DOM Level 2 Specification (November 13, 2000): Changes](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/changes.html)
- [DOM Level 3 Specification (April 7, 2004): Changes](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/changes.html)
- [DOM Living Standard](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-document) and the corresponding [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/whatwg/dom)

Comment: Thanks. I think part of my problem is not quite understanding how that table works.

Answer (score 2):

The HTML Standard is under revision control, with source available on GitHub:

https://github.com/whatwg/html

The source itself is a single file, which is too large for GitHub's online tools to handle. You can clone the repo and investigate history locally. Alternatively they recommend [in their README](https://github.com/whatwg/html#blame) the use of [a third party tool](https://searchfox.org/whatwg-html/source/source) to view annotation online.

Comment: He's asking about the DOM API (e.g. things like `document.getElementById()`, is that part of the HTML spec?

Comment: Yep, the section linked to in the question begins on line 9125 of the source of the HTML Standard as of commit `200ac131`.